# change a window's dpi awareness after creation

Tags: c#, c++, windows, dll, dpi

I'm working on a dll for game maker and I'm running into some issues.
I seems I can't change the dpi settings on an already created window.
Is this true or is there some workaround?
I've been using SetProcessDpiAwareness and SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext.
I was using c# but I don't mind switching to c++ if needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Windows 10 the DPI is process wide and constant. Beginning with [Windows 10 Anniversary Update](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/10/24/high-dpi-scaling-improvements-for-desktop-applications-and-mixed-mode-dpi-scaling-in-the-windows-10-anniversary-update/) you can dynamically change a threads DPI, this is known as [mixed mode DPI scaling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt744321%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it still does not let you dynamically change a windows DPI:

> - When a window is created, its DPI awareness is defined as the DPI awareness of the calling thread at that time.
> - When the window procedure for a window is called, the thread is automatically switched to the DPI awareness context that was in use when the window was created.

The only workaround I can think of is to change the threads DPI and replace the old window with a new instances of your window.